# window.devicePixelRatio browser support

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I have been looking around the web to find what browser support there is for  `window.devicePixelRatio`, without much luck.

Does anyone know what browers/devices support this?

Comment: if you need to support the newer iOS or androids, then this should work. Logically I would say any device with a pixel ratio that is greater than 1 should support this, but who knows... what do you need to do? Perhaps there are other ways to solving your problem

Comment: I think we can use [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio) for check browser compatibility. It has contain both web & mobile

Answer (score 9):

According to [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2012/07/more_about_devi.html) blog post : ( from 2012 )

- `window.devicePixelRatio` is mostly trustworthy on most browsers.
- On iOS devices, multiply `devicePixelRatio` by `screen.width` to get the physical pixel count.
- On Android and Windows Phone devices, divide `screen.width` by `devicePixelRatio` to get the dips count.

**2017 UPDATE:**

> This property returns the ratio of the resolution in physical pixels to the resolution in CSS pixels for the current display device. This value could also be interpreted as the ratio of pixel sizes: the size of one CSS pixel to the size of one physical pixel.

Desktop browsers support:

```
Chrome    Edge    Firefox    Internet Explorer    Opera    Safari
49        (Yes)   49         11                   41       9.1
```

Mobile Browsers:

```
Android     Edge    Firefox     IE Mobile   Opera   Safari Mobile
4.4         (Yes)   ?           ?           all     9.3
```

[Draft Spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-window-devicepixelratio)

Comment: the linked article *is* from 2012. so it's a bit out of date.

Comment: Note: "On iOS devices, multiply devicePixelRatio by screen.width to get the physical pixel count" is no longer true - it gives an incorrect result on iPhone 6+, 6s+ & 7+ due to downsampling.