# Getting the physical screen dimensions / dpi / pixel density in Chrome on Android

Tags: android, javascript, google-chrome

## Question

Is there a safe way to get the actually correct screen physical dimensions in Chrome, on Android? If necessary, old versions of Chrome and Android can be left out of scope.

### Prior research

There are numerous dead-end questions on stackoverflow about getting the actual physical screen dimensions of a device from within javascript (or css). It seems there is no convergence between html api standardization and actual browser implementations in that, not to mention the browser implementation relies on OS api's which in turn rely on hardware providing the right information.

Some prior answers by the way are arcane (year 2011 and the like) in assuming a certain pixel density that prevailed at that time, and therefore useless. Others relate to webkit whereas Chrome blink may have superseded webkit in chrome (?).

I would like to explore the existence of a simple solution by constraining things to only Chrome on Android.

### Note

This is all about a javascript (or css) solution inside the browser, not a solution for a native app.

Comment: Why do you want it?  Physical Screen size means nothing on the web, all we care about is CSS Pixel sizes.

Comment: That's simply wrong. My user interface wants to know things like how large should a button be as the user sees it. you may possibly be thinking too much as a code developer in that ;)

Comment: You have to use CSS pixels all the way, real physical pixels mean nothing on the web unfortunately.

Comment: I am not sure what you are actually saying. Are you saying you don't care what size something shows to your physical user's eyes? because the user's visual cortex isn't wired to the CSS but to the physical world....... at least right now :) or does your comment imply a solution

Comment: While @Kinlan didn't mention it, his point encompasses the fact that percentage-based or viewport based CSS values will accomplish 99% of what you're trying to do. 

i.e. You can size anything proportional to the viewport and create a highly use-able experience while still "caring about your physical user's eyes".

Comment: The size of a button, for example, shouldn't be a percentage of the viewport - but rather large enough to touch. I am not sure how that makes sense for high quality design.

Comment: Does this question/answer help?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911786/what-is-device-pixel-ratio-for

Comment: @matt is absolutely correct. One of the most important aspects of Web UX/UI, especially in a fat-finger world, is making sure the buttons are both appropriate for the pointer--in this case, a finger--as well as appropriately sized for the viewing distance from screen to eye. This new realm of mobile devices have complicated the matter, so physical screen size detection is even more paramount.

Comment: I am 100% with you @matt. I don't understand why Mozilla and Google can't just give us a JavaScript property like `window.screenDensity` that contains the *physical* pixels per inch of the device you and I, matt, can take it from there. `window.screenHeight` and `window.screenWidth` in physical millimeters would be nice too.

Comment: @Kinlan Physical screen size is important in general. This is why native development is more powerful than web development at the moment. In a native environment, I can make a button that is 1 (real-world) inch wide, on all modern devices, for example. This is not currently possible in a web environment, as far as I know. Have I missed something?

Comment: I agree with @matt - I was an entirely different ux on a 5-inch screen than the one I offer on 11 - 28+ inch monitors.

Comment: Answering Kinlan's "Why do you want it?":  I have a graphical app with a polygon.  Each polygon vertex has a drag box, so user can move vertices.  On a touch screen the user's finger obscures the vertex while they are dragging it.  With an API for physical pixel size, then I could show the dragged vertex 5mm (radius of typical human finger tip) above the touch (x,y) pixel position, so user can see  where they are placing the vertex.

Comment: This is useful also when you want to disable some heavy javascript code in mobile devices, but since they have huge resolution, we should know what size the screen is to disable it by physical size.

Comment: holy %$#! was i apparently naive in thinking that CSS "inches" actually meant inches and then architecting a design on the assumption that an inch is an inch only to find my grand designs are literally wrecked by the apparent inability to do something so simple as determine what the screen density is!@

Comment: Yes, it seems like there might be. Current (beta) demonstration page at http://www.hyperspaces.co.uk/device/

Answer (score 136):

You can't really get the real physical dimensions or the actual DPI and even if you could, you can't do anything with them.

This is a pretty long and complex story, so forgive me.

The web and all browsers define 1px as a unit called a CSS pixel.  A CSS pixel is not a real pixel, rather a unit that is deemed to be 1/96th of an inch based on the viewing angle of the device.  This is specified as a [reference pixel](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#reference-pixel).

> The reference pixel is the visual angle of one pixel on a device with
>   a pixel density of 96dpi and a distance from the reader of an arm's
>   length. For a nominal arm's length of 28 inches, the visual angle is
>   therefore about 0.0213 degrees. For reading at arm's length, 1px thus
>   corresponds to about 0.26 mm (1/96 inch).

In 0.26mm of space we might have very many real device pixels.

The browser does this mainly for legacy reasons -  most monitors were 96dpi when the web was born - but also for consistency, in the "old days" a 22px button on a 15 inch screen at 800x600 would be twice the size of a 22px button on a 15 inch monitor at 1600x1200.  In this case the DPI of the screen is actually 2x (twice the resolution horizontally but in the same physical space).  This is a bad situation for the web and apps, so most operating systems devised many ways to abstract pixel values in to device independent units (DIPS on Android, PT on iOS and the **CSS Pixel on the web**).

The iPhone Safari browser was the first (to my knowledge) to introduce the concept of a viewport.  This was created to enable full desktop style applications to render on a small screen.  The viewport was defined to be 960px wide.  This essentially zoomed the page out 3x (iphone was originally 320px) so 1 CSS pixel is 1/3rd of a physical pixel.  When you defined a viewport though you could get this device to match 1 CSS pixel = 1 real pixel at 163dpi.

By using a viewport where the width is "device-width" frees you up from having to set the width of the viewport on a per device basis to the optimal CSS pixel size, the browser just does it for you.

With the introduction of double DPI devices, mobile phone manufacturers didn't want mobile pages to appear 50% smaller so they introduced a concept called devicePixelRatio (first on mobile webkit I believe), this lets them keep 1 CSS pixel to be roughly 1/96th of an inch but let you understand that your assets such as images might need to be twice the size.  If you look at the iPhone series all of their devices say the width of the screen in [CSS pixels is 320px](http://viewportsizes.com/?filter=iphone) even though we know this is not true.

Therefore if you made a button to be 22px in CSS space, the representation on the physical screen is 22 * device pixel ratio.  Actually I say this, it is not exactly this because the device pixel ratio is never exact either, phone manufacturers set it to a nice number like 2.0, 3.0 rather than 2.1329857289918....

In summary, CSS pixels are device independent and let us not have to worry about physical sizes of the screens and the display densities etc.

The moral of the story is: Don't worry about understanding the physical pixel size of the screen.  You don't need it.  50px should look roughly the same across all mobile devices it might vary a little, but the CSS Pixel is our device independent way to build consistent documents and UI's

Resources:

- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/set-the-viewport
- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/size-content-to-the-viewport
- http://viewportsizes.com/
- http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_independent_pixel
- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: I really appreciate the holistic reply and the key hyperlinks! Just one thing about the bottom line you suggest at the bottom... how would 50px (or any other size) physically size roughly the same on all mobile devices? even if putting "phone sized" devices aside, tablets vary by 30% in physical screen size. Would you care to comment or did you imply that if devicePixelRatio or a combination of CSS properties are used by pages, then that statement applies. Thanks!

Comment: @matt it will be the same on tablets.  Like it is with retina mac books.  The goal is that the "CSS Pixel" is relatively uniform across all platforms especially if you set the viewport width=device-width.

Comment: @kinland Very good explanation. I wanted to also point out that though devices "should" and in general do make 50px look roughly the same size, there are some that don't. I'm working on a project who's users often will view the site with a Lenovo Helix. This device makes everything very physically small, cramming a full HD sized viewport into a small space. This makes everything physically smaller compared to most other devices/monitors. And unfortunately there's no way (from what I can tell) to make things bigger for the poor users that have to interact with the UI, other than a browser zoom.

Comment: @Ben There is a way if your UI is responsive, and the device is a tablet and/or a metro/touch/modern view. If you are able to detect the device, you can technically resize the viewport to smaller than the default `device-with`,  making UI elements larger with a slightly smaller UI width.

Comment: @Kinlan Re: "device pixel ratio is never exact either, manufacturers set it to a nice number like 2.0, 3.0 rather than 2.1329857289918." Say what? Do you have an example of that? AFAICT mobile devices give accurate `physical-pixel-width / device-width` ratio...

Comment: @hexalys supposing I could accurately detect the device, how would I make my viewport smaller than the device? Is there a way to do this and still show the display from edge to edge of the device screen and/or browser?

Comment: @Ben Tricky ways especially across browsers, but Yes. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21721335/1647538) for an overall idea. Or this [viewport change demo](https://miketaylr.com/bzla/viewport-change.html) on mobile.

Comment: You said "you can't do anything with them." I disagree. With that info I'd be able to set a font that is *always* 16 points (16/72nds of a real-world inch) in height. That is invaluable, and one of the reasons native development continues to be more powerful than web development.

Comment: @hexalys, we actually just found the nexus 7 (2012) has an very obscure pixel ratio that was only just changed recently from a none uniform one.  will update post.

Comment: @hexalys the pixel ratio is `physical-pixel-width / device-width` but the device width is often a number that they will determine to be "good" and backwards compatible so you can't always safely multiply that out and get the actual number of pixels.

Comment: @Kinlan I agree on that last point. I know there are weird values out there, like IEMobile or Presto. But they are usually based on a flawed design and/or deliberately built on a different calculation basis. I meant that, they don't *deliberately declare a nice number* for the sake of rounding them up, which is somewhat implied by your sentence.

Comment: Actually, a perfectly reasonable use for the real screen size in pixels is to render a background image with the appropriate resolution.

Comment: the link to quirksode opened my eyes ... the title, _A Pixel Is Not_, was my aha moment that the word 'pixel' is being used by different people to describe completely non-dependent things ... a physical pixel IS NOT the same thing as a css pixel .... ahhhhhh breath

Comment: "50px should look roughly the same across all mobile devices"
please prove that using for example a 1200x1920 4 inch phone and a 1000x600 10 inch tablet next to eachother.

Comment: @iloveregex 
There is such a thing as DPR. Such a phone surely has a larger ratio then the tablet. But I agree, that 50px could look totally different. For example 96dpi laptop screen and 150dpi mobile screen, both with pixel ratio 1.0. The difference of element's dimension will be about 50%, which is not roughly the same!

Comment: I also disagree with "you can't do anything with them.": you can detect if the device is a phone or a tablet reliably and assume that user can easily point on top of the screen with their finger or not.

Comment: @iloveregex even worse, 50px on various non-mobile devices does not look roughly the same at ALL as the on-screen size is inversely proportional to the DPI of the screen.

Comment: Very detailed answer, but I don't understand why stating that there nothing we can do with the physical size of the screen. There are many things we can do with this information. For example knowing (or setting) the physical dimension of something on the screen. For example to show something as it would be printed. Applications to augmented reality are also obvious. It would be nice if answers would stick to the question, and not decide what people would like to do.

Comment: Sorry, had to downvote this.  The entire reason I am looking for finding device dimensions is because the same spec elements look tiny on my iPhone and fine on MacBook Pro.  If you can explain where I misunderstand this.

Comment: It looks as if there might possibly be a way after all... After a very long time, this is my solution currently in open beta, (code obfuscated until I have proven it). Tested on Windows / Android / OSX / iOS/Safari/Chrome etc.  http://www.hyperspaces.co.uk/device/

Comment: Do you want to add this to your list of references?
[Point vs pixel: what is the difference?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/199)

Answer (score 10):

There is no way to get physical dimensions of physical pixels or displays in a web app (no web API for it).

---

Based on Matanster's answer in which he observed SVG properties such as `screenPixelToMillimeterX`, I made a test to see if they work:

(EDIT: these properties are deleted (or never were) from spec, and browsers may no longer have (or never had) them, moving us further away from ever knowing actual physical display sizing).

```
// on Macbook Pro Retina (2880x1800, 15.4"), is the calculated diagonal size
// approximately 15.4? Let's see...

var svgEl = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
var screenWidthMillimeters = svgEl.screenPixelToMillimeterX * 2880;
var screenHeightMillimeters = svgEl.screenPixelToMillimeterY * 1800;
var screenDiagonalMillimeters = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(screenWidthMillimeters, 2) + Math.pow(screenHeightMillimeters, 2)); // pythagorean theorem
var screenDiagonalInches = (screenDiagonalMillimeters / 10 / 2.54); // (mm / 10mm/cm) / 2.54cm/in = in

console.log("The calculated diagonal of the screen is "+screenDiagonalInches+" inches. \nIs that close to the actual 15.4\"?");
```

This is the output:

```
The calculated diagonal of the screen is 35.37742738560738 inches. 
Is that close to the actual value of 15.4?
```

Nope.

There seems to be no way to get real physical values in a web browser yet.

Comment: I'm not sure what answer you are referring to (I don't see a "Matt" anywhere), but i get NaN due to `svgEl.screenPixelToMillimeterX` apparently not being defined.

Comment: I got the same result as you, 15.4" but my screen is actually 21", it's too different

Comment: @Michael He changed his name to "matanster" and deleted his answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24780546/454780).

Comment: @TJS101 Unless there is a new web API I'm not aware of, it is impossible to get dimensions of physical pixels, and we can only get dimensions of CSS pixels, noting that CSS `in` units (and other "physical" units) are not accurate (they are relative to CSS pixels, not physical pixels, and `1in` will therefore vary from device to device). Also the `thisDevice` object appears to be empty for me when I visit in Chrome in Linux. I really do wish we had API for physical screen dimensions.

Comment: @trusktr Thank you for pointing this out. Older browsers don't support some of the newer functions I used, so I have added a "compatibility mode" that identifies if things like visualViewport are not supported and provides a cut down version of the demo page. https://www.hyperspaces.co.uk/device/

Comment: @TJS101 That still doesn't help, VisualViewport units are CSS pixels, not physical pixels, so the blue box on the screen is not 1 inch by 1 inch. On my screen, it is 0.625 in x 0.625 in according to my physical ruler. So there is no way to get *physical* pixel dimensions.

Comment: @trustkr what is the make and model of the device? Or can you send me a message using the inbuilt email so I can see the device stats? I am curious and determined to find out what it is so I can check my working…. Thanks

Comment: @TJS101 Unless you will make a very long table of devices to look up dimensions from instead of using VisualViewport, it won't matter if I tell you my device. I tested on many devices over the years, and on _all of them_ one CSS inch has never been an actual inch. See this: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/614

Comment: @trusktr The only thing I was using VisualViewport for was to do the pinch / zoom bits on modern (ES6) capable devices. I did not use it for the calculations themselves. Fortunately I do not need a table of every device to do this. This work is currently in open Beta, and your device details would have helped to double check the mathematics.

Comment: @TJS101 My device details: System 76 Oryx Pro (64GB RAM, with Nvidia 16GB option). Your math is probably as correct as it can be, but we can't get physical pixel dimensions with the current APIs.

Comment: @trustkr My code supports Windows, OSX, Android, iOS, surface, and some other odd mobiles. I don’t have a Linux laptop to test (but now I wish I had!) thanks for the information, I’ll see what I can do.

Comment: @TJS101 Do you get what I'm saying though? It doesn't matter if you support every OS that ever existed: in all OSes, the major browsers that currently exist _do not_ tell you physical pixel dimensions in any way. It is impossible to get this information, unless you build an external list of every monitor/display ever made along with and their physical dimensions (similar to WURFL in the other answer).

Comment: @trusktr I completely get what you are saying. However, testing on those systems seems to indicate that it does actually work.

Comment: @TJS101 Do you have proof? Can you show a photo of your ruler showing 1 CSS inch is 1 physical inch with default zoom? This has never been true on any of my devices (and I've had many).

Comment: @trusktr That's not what I meant. 1 CSS inch is not 1 physical inch. That why I have spent months perfecting this code to accurately calculate the PPI of a device and then draw a 1 inch square on the screen. The method does not use CSS measurements, or a database of all possible devices. It is just a short cut through the mathematics of the metrics provided by any device (tested so far). Seems to work well, although I am still fine tuning in Beta.

Comment: @TJS101 I wish you were right. On my Pixel 6, the blue box is about 26.9mm (not the expected 25.4mm).

Comment: @trusktr this is why I call it an open beta. Send me the email details and it will. All I need is the model and pixel density ratio. I can see the rest from other sources for the device. (Assuming it is a 6 not a 6a or a 6xl)

Comment: @TJS101 If you need the device details, then you are building a database of devices. The info is online, it is a "Google Pixel 6 Pro" (the most expensive one).

Comment: @trusktr Thank you! if have fixed the maths for all things with devicePixelRatio=4.

Answer (score 5):

You can get that info with WURFL:

[Device display properties](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/help_doc.php#display)

The attributes are called:

```
resolution_(width|height)

physical_display_(width|height)
```

Long version:

The best and most reliant strategy to achieve this is to send the `user agent string` from the browser to a DB like `WURFL` (or another) up to date DB that can provide the needed information.

[User Agent string](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp)

This is a piece of information that all modern browsers can provide; it exposes information about the device and it's OS. It is just not meaningful enough to your application without the help of a dictionary like `WURFL`.

[WURFL](http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=130)

This is a database commonly used to *detect* device properties.

With it, you may be able to accurately support most of the popular devices on the market.
I would post a code demo but one is available with the download on the `WURFL` site. You can find such a demo on the examples/demo folder that is downloaded with the library.

[Download WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/php_index.php)

Here is more information and explanation about checking the physical size and resolution:
http://www.scientiamobile.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=286

Answer (score 5):

As a complement to the ”there's no good solution to this problem” answer, just check the units you can use on CSS https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

```
Unit    Description
cm      centimeters
mm      millimeters
in      inches (1in = 96px = 2.54cm)
px *    pixels (1px = 1/96th of 1in)
pt      points (1pt = 1/72 of 1in)
pc      picas (1pc = 12 pt)

* Pixels (px) are relative to the viewing device.
For low-dpi devices, 1px is one device pixel (dot) of the display.
For printers and high resolution screens 1px implies multiple device pixels.
```

With this description it *seems* there is a solution. `cm`, `mm` and `in` would be used to draw something with the same size independently of the screen size and resolution. With this in mind, you can expect that at least one of `px`, `pt` or `pc` can be used to draw at the pixel level, for whatever precision you would like to use (otherwise, what's the point on having millions of pixels, right?). Well, no. All of the units are fractions of a metric unit, making all of these units just different scales. And the worst in the story is the fact that none of these are accurate. Just play with the w3schools example (draw a 20cm line and measure it with a ruler).

So in the end:
- there is no way to draw something with physical dimensions accurately (which should be the case with `cm`, `mm`, `in`, and eventually `pt` and `pc`).
- there is no way to draw something with the same size independently of the screen size and resolution (which should be the case with at least `px`).

This is both an implementation problem (actual screen size not being used) and design problem (why should `px` be independent of the screen size while there is already so many units for that).

Answer (score 4):

You can create any page element and set its width using real physical units. For example

```
<div id="meter" style="width:10cm"></div>
```

And then get its width in pixels. For example html code below (i used JQuery) shows device screen width in centimeters

```
<script>
var pixPer10CM = $('#meter').width();
var CMPerPix = 10 / pixPer10CM;
var widthCM = screen.width * CMPerPix;

alert(widthCM);
</script>
```

Comment: Wow I never realized you could do this with css. How accurate is this? How does your browser know the physical dimensions of your screen? Is the browser compatibility for this on http://caniuse.com somewhere? I can't find it.

Comment: W3C site says: "In the past, CSS required that implementations display absolute units correctly even on computer screens. But as the number of incorrect implementations outnumbered correct ones and the situation didn't seem to improve, CSS abandoned that requirement in 2011. Currently, absolute units must work correctly only on printed output and on high-resolution devices. CSS doesn't define what “high resolution” means. But as low-end printers nowadays start at 300 dpi and high-end screens are at 200 dpi, the cut-off is probably somewhere in between."

Comment: I think that browser like any other native application can get device resolution through OS API, provided to OS by device driver. Accuracy depends on this information.

Comment: But device resolution is not the same as actual physical dimensions. A 14" laptop and 15" laptop could have the same resolution.

Comment: No! You can't. 10cm in Css will have different size in reality. It's pure matter of luck if it will actually have 10cm, 12cm or 7cm. Here's my jsfiddle demo based on that solution returning wrong values, since browsers always behave like they have pixels per inch (dpi): https://jsfiddle.net/Lzsm3zo9/

Comment: @DariuszSikorski Works on my PC

Comment: This doesn't work, "physical" units in all of today's browsers a certain size relative to CSS pixels rather than physical pixels. On my screen, for example, a 1in div actually measures 0.625 real-world inches.

Answer (score 3):

As a response to zehelvion reply about using WURFL to find the resolution, it is also worth mentioning that WURFL is also available as a [JavaScript snippet](https://web.wurfl.io/#learnmore).

In the free edition offered at [wurfl.io](http://wurfl.io), you won't get information about the screen and resolution though (only device name, form factor and mobile/not mobile), but there is also a commercial version with [more capabilities available here](http://www.scientiamobile.com/page/wbe).

Comment: I suggest this to be in the comments to that particular answer.

Comment: this is a ridiculously complicated solution to something that should just be provided natively by the browser.

Answer (score 2):

I tackled this problem with one of my web projects http://www.vinodiscover.com The answer is that you can't know for certain what the physical size is, but you can get an approximation. Using JS and / or CSS, you can find the width and height of the viewport / screen, and the pixel density using media queries. For example: iPhone 5 (326 ppi) = 320px by 568px and a 2.0 pixel density, while a Samsung Galaxy S4 (441ppi) = 360px x 640px and a 3.0 pixel density. Effectively a 1.0 pixel density is around 150 ppi.

Given this, I set my CSS to show 1 column when the width is less than 284px, regardless of pixel density; then two columns between 284px and 568px; then 3 columns above 852px. It's  much more simple then it seems, since the browsers now do the pixel density calculations automatically.

http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html

Comment: In native development you can get the exact value. +1 for native, -1 for web.

Comment: Can you get the exact physical size in Android?

Comment: Yeah: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android

Answer (score 2):

CSS pixels aren't really our "device independent pixel". Web platform consists of variety of device types. While CSS pixel seem to look pretty consistent on handhelds, it will be 50% bigger on a typical 96dpi desktop monitor. See my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241183/css-pixel-density-independent-design-css-pixel-50-larger-on-desktop) . This is really not a bad thing in some cases, e.g. fonts should be larger on a larger screen, since distance to the eye is bigger. But ui element dimensions should be pretty consistent. Let's say your app has a top bar, you would rather want it to be the same thickness on desktop and mobiles, by default it will be 50% smaller, which is not good, because touchable elements should be bigger. The only workaround I have found is to apply different styles based on device DPI.

You can get screen DPI in JavaScript with window.devicePixelRatio . Or CSS query:

```
@media  only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
    only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 13/10),
    only screen and (min-resolution: 120dpi)
    {
     /* specific styles for handhelds/ high dpi monitors*/
    }
```

I don't know  how applying this would work on a high dpi desktop monitor though. Perhaps elements would be too small. It is really a shame that the web platform doesn't offer anything better. I guess that implementation of dip wouldn't be too hard.

Comment: no, you can't.  media queries are doing this stupid "assume 96dpi" crap, i.e. they are *lying to you* about what the read DPI is.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed in your comments that you were actually concerned with the size that buttons and so on appear to the viewer.

I was having the same problem, until I discovered that it just was a matter of adding a meta tag to the HTML header to set the initial scale:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Answer (score 0):

[JqueryMobile width of element](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a2/experiments/api-viewer/docs/width/index.html)

```
$(window).width();   // returns width of browser viewport
$(document).width(); // returns width of HTML document
```

[JqueryMobile Height of element](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a2/experiments/api-viewer/docs/height/index.html)

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
```

Good Luck
Danny117

Comment: Those are virtual dimensions, which are not always physical real-world dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Using the getPPI() function ([Mobile web: how to get physical pixel size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456455/mobile-web-how-to-get-physical-pixel-size)), to obtain a one inch  id use this formula:

```
var ppi = getPPI();
var x   = ppi * devicePixelRatio * screen.pixelDepth / 24;
$('#Cubo').width (x);
$('#Cubo').height(x);

<div id="Cubo" style="background-color:red;"></div>
```

Comment: why pixelDepth?! isn't pixelDepth related to color depth, in which case I wonder how is it relevant to the calculation here....

Answer (score 0):

Heh wish I could answer this but geeks building APIs don't provide the basic necessities and abstract things a bit too much at times.

BTW I have 40 years of UI and software design design experience and have been pushing to have just this for what seems like forever since before the days of "VESA" drivers :).

For touch screen I had a thing I called "fingerSize()"  which was the number of pixels to be 1cm ( very close to diameter of average touch area of finger) but the root datmum is  "dpcm".

The other thing you want for a display is "angle of view"
The type of display device for viewing and touch function pretty much defines viewing distance.

```
    (Not code but I wanted fixed width font)

    Hand held - Phone/Tablet         25cm 
    Touch screen / Desktop Monitor   40cm         ( seated or standing at a counter
                                                    with partially extended arm )
    "Personal" Touch kiosk        50cm -> 80cm ( a bit further away standing 
                                                 extended arms and standing back 
                                                 to view )
    Presentation Screen.          any distance ( angle of view derived from pixel
                                                 width of device. An ideal conventional cinema 
                                                 seat (as opposed to imax or immersive) 
                                                 you want about 50 degrees
                                                 between edges of the screen. from viewer POV )

    So what you want universally available is:

    device usage type.
    finger size in pixels (dots per CM)
    pixel dimensions of display.

    Then internally, when laying out and drawing you want the size/shape of a pixel 
    for the current transform.
```

This is what we try to provide in our APIs But alas hard to get in many cases.

Answer (score -2):

You can get a rough estimation of size, but it's not accurate.

I've put together an example which I've tested on a couple devices to see what the results were. My iPhone 6 returns values about 33% larger. My 27" desktop monitor on my Mac reported as a 30" monitor.

```js
var $el = document.createElement('div');
$el.style.width = '1cm';
$el.style.height = '1cm';
$el.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
$el.style.position = 'fixed';
$el.style.bottom = 0;
document.body.appendChild($el);
var screenDiagonal = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((window.screen.width / $el.offsetWidth), 2) + Math.pow((window.screen.height / $el.offsetHeight), 2));
var screenDiagonalInches = (screenDiagonal / 2.54);
var str = [
  '1cm (W): ' + $el.offsetWidth + 'px',
  '1cm (H): ' + $el.offsetHeight + 'px',
  'Screen width: ' + window.screen.width + 'px',
  'Screen height: ' + window.screen.height + 'px',
  'Browser width: ' + window.innerWidth + 'px',
  'Browser height: ' + window.innerHeight + 'px',
  'Screen available width: ' + window.screen.availWidth + 'px',
  'Screen available height: ' + window.screen.availHeight + 'px',
  'Screen width: ' + (window.screen.width / $el.offsetWidth).toFixed(2) + 'cm',
  'Screen height: ' + (window.screen.height / $el.offsetHeight).toFixed(2) + 'cm',
  'Screen diagonal: ' + screenDiagonal.toFixed(2) + 'cm',
  'Screen diagonal: ' + screenDiagonalInches.toFixed(2) + 'in',
  'Device Pixel Ratio: ' + (window.devicePixelRatio || 1)
].join('\n');
var $pre = document.createElement('pre');
$pre.innerHTML = str;
document.body.appendChild($pre);
```

http://codepen.io/kus/full/xOAPYB/

Comment: My 40inch reported as a 22inch.

Comment: Not accurate for me neither. I think the problem is due to `window.devicePixelRatio`. It is 1 on an Apple Thunderbolt screen, and 2 on an Macbook Pro Touchbar 15". Is this value always an integer? This wouldn't make sense since it is a ratio. Other elements: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385573/window-devicepixelratio-browser-support

Comment: It might not have been much good back in 2016, but it reports a screen size of 45" for my desktop PC (real size is 40") and 10" for my Galaxy S10+, which is both close enough to i.e. differentiate between different scaled versions of UIs and documents. Not sure why you prefix all variables with $ though.