# How can we get the real size of the screen in inches with Dart?

Tags: responsive-design, dart

- window.innerHeight
- window.innerWidth

gives you the size of the window  in "CSS pixel" not in real ones.

To develop a responsive application we need to know the real size of the screen to adapt the behavior of the application.

[The solution in the Javascript world doesn't seem good enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680629/getting-the-physical-screen-dimensions-dpi-pixel-density-in-chrome-on-androi)

How can we do that properly in Dart?

Comment: This is not really a Dart question. I guess you can increase your chances for getting a good answer by adding other labels like CSS or JavaScript. If you know how to do it in JS it's probably the same or similar in Dart.

Comment: There are some answers on the Javascript side. I just wanted to do it in pure Dart if possible.

Comment: You could add the JS code to your question or at least link to the code that shows what you try to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't do it in JavaScript you can't do it in Dart neither. This is not a Dart limitation but a browser limitation. If the browser API doesn't provide this information you are out of luck.

Comment: https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/be/dartdoc-viewer/dart:html.Window#id_devicePixelRatio : window.devicePixelRatio do you know this one ? For the moment, it's always a null value but it can be a starting point.

Comment: Also only relative information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785643/what-exactly-is-device-pixel-ratio

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the real screen size because there are no information provided to you that could give you about he physical size.

What's wrong about using pixel width/height and scaling up according to them?

Comment: a small mobile can have a very good resolution so the fact that width/height is high do not tell you that the real screen is big.

for a small screen you need big button so that the user can actually reach them with its finger.