# How do I know how many physical inches a device screen has?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, css, jquery-mobile

I have a website that needs to distinguish between mobile phones, tablets, and ordinary laptops.  Normally I could use an asp.net function to tell, but the complication is that I want tablets to be treated as NOT being mobile devices.  Any device with a screen diagonal greater than 7.5 inches would get the normal website, and any device with a screen dialog of less than this would get the mobile version of the site.

First I thought all I need to do is get the screen.width (I'm using JavaScript) and screen.height, apply the pythagorean theorem to get the length of the diagonal (in pixels) and then divide by pixels-per-inch.
The issue is this: Is "pixels-per-inch" always 96 for every type of device?
If not, I can't do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know about CSS media queries?  Are you planning to have two separate websites, one for regular/large devices and another for smaller devices, with each website being on its own domain?

Comment: Related (duplicate? I didn't vote because if I did, it would close the question immediately and I'm not sure enough): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680629/getting-the-physical-screen-dimensions-dpi-pixel-density-in-chrome-on-androi

Comment: It would be one website, but with a different home page, which has different links, based on whether I'm dealing with a small screen or not.

Comment: @MarcAudet media queries can't tell you the physical dimensions of your screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I know how many physical inches a device screen has?

You can't.

> Is "pixels-per-inch" always 96 for every type of device?

No, not remotely. Not only do you have the issue of [Retina displays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retina_Display), but if I have a notebook computer with a screen resolution of 1280x768, if the screen is 15.1" it's going to have a lower PPI than if the screen is 10.1".

Comment: *When* is this going to change?