# More rows in larger physical display

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a data table that displays 12 rows in a smaller screen. The resolution of screen is 1280x1024. I have to display more rows, say 20, in a device with larger physical screen but with same resolution as of smaller device.

How to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

if really you mean same pixel resolution but different physical size, then answer is you cant (at least not at desktops)

there is some not reliable workaround for phones

[Getting the physical screen dimensions / dpi / pixel density in Chrome on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680629/getting-the-physical-screen-dimensions-dpi-pixel-density-in-chrome-on-androi)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I think CSS Media queries is probably your best bet.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: No, media query won't help. Since resolution is same for both devices.

Comment: Hmm and using the dpi option on css media queries wont get you what you want either... Wish I had a better idea for you!