# How to set physical dimensions (like actual inches) for elements?

Tags: html, css, screen

My end goal is to display an image of the same exact size on every screen (yes, I really do need this for something).

I started reading about how to get the user's screen size [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680629/getting-the-physical-screen-dimensions-dpi-pixel-density-in-chrome-on-androi) - and the answer seems to be that it's impossible (without calling an API which attempts to guess the actual device based on some params).

I then remembered that css has physical dimension units for sizing elements and decided to test on my screen. I set dimensions like so:

```
<div style = "background-color:black; height: 5in; width: 3in;"></div>
```

and then put a physical 3"x 5" (7.6cm x 12.7cm) flashcard against the screen.

It was significantly off in size.

Fun note - setting size in mm was ridiculously off - I expected to get the same results as with inches.

With that said, is there a way to do what I need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In CSS, one inch does not equal one physical inch. It equals 96px.

This section of the spec may help you:

[**5.2. Absolute lengths: the `cm`, `mm`, `q`, `in`, `pt`, `pc`, `px` units**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths)

[image]

> The absolute length units are fixed in relation to each other and
>   anchored to some physical measurement.
>
> If the anchor unit is the pixel unit, the physical units might not
>   match their physical measurements.
>
> Alternatively if the anchor unit is a physical unit, the pixel unit
>   might not map to a whole number of device pixels

Comment: Thanks, that helps.

Comment: @VSO What? How?  This tells me nothing about how I might actually go about creating an element that is (e.g.) exactly 1 inch in width on every device that it is displayed!

Comment: @Michael Long story short - it is impossible to get physical dimensions. There are libraries which will detect your screen / device and try to adjust to that, if you REALLY need it, but they are all a pain.

Comment: Also, if you click on the link provided in the answer, there is a much more detailed explanation. This answer is meant to serve as an introduction. It's general in nature. I provided the link reference for those wanting more details. @Michael