# For a full-screen canvas, how do I determine browser client size?

Tags: html5-canvas, webgl

I've tried various ways of determining the size of the browser's client area in terms of physical pixels, but I get a non-integer result on mobile devices.

For example: `window.outerWidth * window.devicePixelRatio` on a Pixel 2 with Chrome yields `1081.5` even though I know that the browser's client area is actually `1080` pixels wide.

Another way of seeing this is going to [mydevice.io](https://www.mydevice.io/) and multiplying `JS screen.width` with `JS pixel-ratio`.

Is there a better way to determine physical client size?

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680629/getting-the-physical-screen-dimensions-dpi-pixel-density-in-chrome-on-androi

Comment: Nice find!  The predominant answer in that question is "do not do that" but I want to draw pixel-perfect text in WebGL, and I'd like to set up a correct framebuffer size for doing this in my canvas element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ResizeObserver` and or `devicePixelContentBox` can be used for this, at least on some browsers.

More information is available in the following article:

https://web.dev/device-pixel-content-box/

Comment: for reference here's a few threads: https://www.khronos.org/webgl/public-mailing-list/public_webgl/1406/msg00019.php, https://github.com/KhronosGroup/WebGL/issues/2460

Comment: Cool that someone is solving this problem, but wouldn't more accurate `devicePixelRatio` suffice as a solution?

Comment: It doesn't sound like any higher res devicePixelRatio would help. It looks like every layout engine does different things to decide exactly how many pixels to make something whether they use floor or ceil or round and when they use them in what order with what other options (borders, padding, margins, etc...) such that there is no simple answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <p><strong>Note:</strong> The innerWidth and innerHeight properties are not supported in IE8 and earlier.</p>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var w = window.innerWidth;
        var h = window.innerHeight;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Width: " + w + "<br>Height: " + h;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: This returns the width in terms of CSS pixels.  My question is about physical pixels.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to exclude client taskbars, you can use `window.screen.availHeight` and `window.screen.availWidth`.

Else, use `window.screen.height` and `window.screen.width`.

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_screen.asp)

Comment: `window.screen.width` and `window.screen.availWidth` both return CSS pixels.  My question is about physical pixels.

Comment: My bad, I didn't understand that, and I don't even know the difference. Good luck