# Why is my display resolution different from screen.width * devicePixelRatio?

Tags: javascript, css, resolution

On the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio) on `devicePixelRatio` it says:

> (devicePixelRatio) tells the browser how many of the screen's actual pixels should be used to draw a single CSS pixel.

... so I would expect that my display horizontal resolution would be:

`window.devicePixelRatio * window.screen.width` = 2 * 1792 = 3584

... but no. My display horizontal resolution is 3072.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the specification is not accurate enough here.

> (devicePixelRatio) tells the browser how many of the screen's **actual pixels** should be used to draw a single CSS pixel.

It's should be something like:

> (devicePixelRatio) tells the browser how many of the screen's **actual CSS pixels** should be used to draw a single CSS pixel.

Because those "actual pixels" are not actually actual. No pun intended.

I found [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21767407) to a similar question, but I don't like the “you don't need it” rhetoric. TL;DR - The browser does this mainly for legacy reasons.

Also, I found a huge topic on [w3c github](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/614) about "Ability to address actual physical size", in CSS, but anyway. And there are so many "meh, it's not that simple... you know..." messages. I like this one: "there is no clear concept of what a px is".

Turns out that actually you can get the real aspect ratio. At least it works for me. I have a MacBook with a 15-inch display. The real resolution is **2880x1800**. In the settings, I have a resolution **1680x1050** (on which *window.screen* is relying). And a real aspect ratio is **1.6**, not **2** *(hello window.devicePixelRatio)*.

The [aspectRatio property from MediaTrackConstraints](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints/aspectRatio) returns the real aspect ratio: 1.6.

```js
const [track] = (await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia()).getVideoTracks();
console.log(track.getSettings().aspectRatio);
```

But there is one big caveat, this whole "Media Stream API" is about capturing video from the screen, that's why you have to get permissions for it to work. I couldn't find anything else that returns the real aspect ratio but this.

That's all I found in an hour or so, I hope there is enough information to make some conclusions.