# How do I calculate the dpi of mobile device screens but adjust to make object representing in real world mm?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, screen-size

I am trying to represent a square in pixels on all screen sizes and have the measurement be accurate.
So this works on desktop screen solutions from 1920 to 1080 and up.

```
  getDpi() {
    let screenWidth = screen.width;
    let screenHeight = screen.height;
    let widthInches = screenWidth / screen.width * devicePixelRatio;
    let heightInches = screenHeight / screen.height * devicePixelRatio;
    let diagonalInches = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(widthInches, 2) + Math.pow(heightInches, 2));
    let diagonalPixels = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(screenWidth, 2) + Math.pow(screenHeight, 2));
    let dpi = diagonalPixels / diagonalInches;
    return dpi;
  }
```

When I changed to a mobile device the square is much smaller. It looks like because the dpi of mobiles are much higher this is throwing off the calculation. If I multiple the dpi by four for example then the square looks like a more accurate size on a mobile screen. Bu I want a more accurate and solid way to do this?

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Related question: [Getting the physical screen dimensions / dpi / pixel density](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21680629/943435)

Comment: @Yogi yet not even close to what i asked